# Matlab outer product like function? How?

Tags: matlab, outer-join

I have the following computation I'd like to vectorize in matlab.

I have a N x 3 array, call it `a`.
I have a 4 x 1 cell array of function handles, call them `b`.

I would like to create an Nx4 matrix `c`, such that `c(i,j) = b{j}(a(i,:)`.

`b` is actually an array, but I don't know how to write down my representation for c in a format that matlab would understand that uses a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function handles work on arrays (i.e. `b{j}(a)` returns a Nx1 array in your example), you can use [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) and [CELL2MAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html) to generate your output array:

```
c = cell2mat( cellfun( @(bFun)bFun(a),b,'UniformOutput',false) );
```

If your function handles only work on individual rows (i.e. `b{j}` needs to be applied to every row of `a` separately, you can throw [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) into the mix (readability suffers a bit though; basically, you're applying each element of `b` via cellfun to each row of `a` via arrayfun):

```
c = cell2mat(...
       cellfun( @(bFun)arrayfun(...
            @(row)bFun(a(row,:)),1:size(a,1)),...
       b,'UniformOutput',false) ...
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

[pdist2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/pdist2.html) almost solves the problem above.  Probably someone more clever than me can figure out how to shoe horn the two together.